# How long does it take for the ethereum blockchain to synchronize?

Tags: mist, blocks

For the past few days I've been synchronizing my mist wallet with the blockchain (using geth). My laptop has been working all day and all night. I've already synced more than 880000 blocks. **How many more blocks do I need to download?**

Comment: Thanks for all who halp me! Today's in night i'm do over sincing with blockchain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take a look at the Ethereum Network Status page found here: https://ethstats.net/ to see which block the network is at. Currently, the best block is #998,717.

Comment: Thx for you too. i'll see this page. Too many blocks....